# messages.getHistory не возвращает непрочитанные сообщения

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Появилась проблема с vk api. Метод messages.getHistory должен возвращать историю диалога,но он не возвращает непрочитанные(новые) сообщения. Как мне получить непрочитанные сообщения? Пример запроса ниже

```
$request_params = http_build_query(array(
     'offset' => 0,
     'count' => 50, 
     'extended' => 1, 
     'peer_id'=> $peer_id, 
     'rev' => 0, 
     'start_message_id' => -1 ,
     'access_token' => $token, 
     'v' => '5.103' 
));
$options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => $request_params
        )
);
$result = file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.getHistory',false, stream_context_create($options));
```

Comment: Что значит не возвращает непрочитанные сообщения? Метод прекрасно работает, и отдает каждое сообщение, в том числе и непрочитанное.

Comment: не возвращает не прочитанные сообщения. посмотрите сами и другой метод в документации я не нашел. Может запрос не правильно отправляю, чтобы получить полностью диалог? Если сообщение прочитаю, то мне показывает снова сообщение

Comment: Во-первых, можно обойтись обычным get-запросом, во-вторых только что, лично тестил и мне вернул все сообщения последние (в том числе и непрочитанные). Чтобы получить полный диалог, делайте смещение (параметр `offset`), и желательно делать это через метод [`execute`](https://vk.com/dev/execute).

Comment: А куда смещение делать,если offset =0 и хочу получить последние 50 сообщений?

Comment: так я отправляю этот параметр. я не могу получить последние 50 сообщений вместе с непрочитанными

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил задачу.Нельзя использовать параметры rev и start_message_id одновременно